# Github: Page Build Issue

Tags: cloudflare

19:44:50.882    Initializing build environment. This may take up to a few minutes to complete

19:46:44.622    Success: Finished initializing build environment

19:46:44.622    Cloning repository…

19:46:46.424    Failed: an internal error occurred

The repo seems fine to me, the error says nothing.
I cant find any place on how to log more details or reach out to CF

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yep GitHub is having a few issues right now. This should be unrelated though so the most common cause for this issue is a submodule (usually a private one). Please have a look if that’s what may be causing this. You can just remove the module part and have the files in the repo to solve that (not ideal we know)

Comment: Yup, sounds like a submodule issue. I've no issues with build at the moment.